# Should "the Music Industry" be capitalised?

Tags: grammar, capitalization

Should "the Music Industry" be capitalised?

Title of my essay:

> Data Mining in the Music Industry

Comment: You can check by looking up _music industry_ whether the phrase is usually capitalised outside titles (Wikipedia is helpful). The question of whether to capitalise various words in titles when they are not otherwise regularly capitalised has been addressed on ELU before. There are different styles.

Comment: Perhaps you have a style guide to refer to for your essay title. In the case of a song title, all except the conjunctions and prepositions would be capitalised - but quite often *every* word is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the title, it should. In the text, it should not. It's not a proper noun.

If music is the first word of a sentence, capitalize the M.